# "dyld`__abort_with_payload" error on iPhone 5s device

Tags: xcode8.2, ios10.2, swift3

I'm trying to run my app on device (iphone 5s) and I got this error when the device tries to run my app. Then it only shows white screen. What's wrong with my device? My code works fine when I use simulator.

Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 12):

I tried everything whatever I can do. Finally I solved it by disabling "Enable guard Malloc" from diagnostics. Now I can able to run the app on device.

Comment: Where can i disable guard malloc feature?

Comment: Edit Scheme > Run > Diagnostics

Comment: Is Apple even looking into these bugs?

Answer (score 10):

project cleaning helped me out

Answer (score 1):

Make Sure Custom Frmaeworks/libs are included **Embedded Binaries** Section(Under General Tab) too along with build phases.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem when I changed the iPhone developer Keychain in my Mac from default to always trust. Coming back to system default work

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Possibly there are more sources for this stack trace on a crash but one cause is not including a reason description, post-iOS10, when attempting to use a camera or microphone or other similar device.

In working with an app that had not been updated past iOS9 I found this error when trying to use the microphone to make a recording. Adding `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription` in `Info.plist` fixed the problem. There are similar keys required for other devices; see [Technical Q&A 1937](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1937/_index.html) for a list of required keys.

(iTunes Connect will reject an app that does not include a required key also.)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar crash. It happened only if I had 3 UITextFields in this order: email, password, password. For password fields property isSecureTextEntry is set to true. For make it crash I changed the focus to one of the password fields, switched to the main screen and back to the app. Sometimes it happened on second or third switching between main screen and app.

So, in my case the reason was Firebase/Performance pod. I’ve removed it for a while — this fixed the bug.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when running my app on a new target iOS version. I updated my pods and the issue was fixed. This can be done by navigating to the project folder including the Podfile and running 'pod update'.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I did three things.

1. disabling "Enable guard Malloc" from diagnostics
2. clean build folder and rebuild.
3. Then it showed me more specific error messages basically telling me that I forgot to put usage description for accessing the camera. So after adding the description message, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and updating iOS on the device solved it.